# iphone Pop screens from navigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I want to pop more than one controller that means If I have totally 6 screens. Sometimes I have to come to 2nd view controller or 3rd controller from 6 th controll.

I know how to pop the current controller or poping till root view controller. But need to pop till particular controller.

Can any one please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UINavigationController` you have a method called `- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`.

You can look for your `UIViewController` in the `viewControllers` property, and then pop to the view controller you want.